# How can I pass an instance variable to a placeholder in form_form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, placeholder, form-for

I'm trying to pass an instance variable to a placeholder in form_for:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :number %>
      <em>(add 1 + area code w/ no spaces; i.e. 15555555555)</em><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :phone, :placeholder => @phone_number.phone_number %>
    </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
```

When I do I get 'undefined method `phone_number' for nil:NilClass. @phone_number is set the same controller as the view

...here is the corresponding controller

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
 before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
 #before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    @phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_or_create_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number][:phone_number])

    redirect_to welcome_index_path
   end
```

Comment: The syntax looks correct, but `@phone_number` is nil for some reason. Could you post the controller where @`phone_number` is set?

Comment: class PhoneNumbersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @phone_number = PhoneNumber.new
  end

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit return and sent the wrong text.  This is in my resgistrations controller set up by Devise:

Comment: class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
 before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
 #before_filter :update_sanitized_params, if: :devise_controller?

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    @phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_or_create_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number][:phone_number])


    redirect_to welcome_index_path
   end

Comment: @ztredded edit question again and post controller action code. don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `redirect_to` creates a new HTTP request, and instance variables like `@phone_number` aren't persisted across requests. Instead you can `render` a view directly from this controller action:

```
def new
  @phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_or_create_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number][:phone_number])
  render welcome_index_path
end
```